Apparent articulation changes with common cold, esp s > ð, p > b
The way we talk changes when we have a cold. Listeners often either genuinely or humorously misinterpret the phonemes uttered. In English, some common changes are apparent [s] -> [ð] and [p] -> [b]. For example "happy" -> "habby", "saddening" -> "thaddening".
Are there general patterns in these "mishearings" (for example: voiceless to voiced) and what causes them? Is there a principal underlying factor (eg nasal blockage, thinckened saliva, etc)? It's often portrayed as being due to having a blocked nose, but the apparent changes seem to be unrelated to nasal articulation. Perhaps it's the sinuses, but I'm unclear as to the role of sinuses in articulation.

The change I'm most familiar with is nasals > voiced stops, which does come from the nose being blocked.

@Draconis But voicing of plosives is also a common stereotype, even though voiced plosives ought, if anything, to be more difficult to produce with a blocked nose. Quite a stereotypical example, I think, is Neville Longbottom in Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix (even though he’s actually got a broken, bloody nose rather than a cold): ‘We’ll dake her wid us,’ said Neville firmly. ‘I’ll carry her – you’re bedder at fighding dem dan I ab’ (/k/ seems to be left alone, but /t/ and /p/ are represented as ⟨d⟩ and ⟨b⟩ – also note /θ, ð/ → ⟨d⟩).

Exactly @JanusBahsJacquet . I suspect it's because plosives don't exactly correspond voiced and unvoiced in English (cf pronunciation of Pakistan), and something other than voicing is giving us that cue.
